# How do I label equations without the chapter number?

Tags: equations

I have an equation, such as:

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\chapter{hello}
\begin{equation}
x=1
\end{equation} 
\end{document}
```

And the equation appears as "x=1 (1.1)".

What I want is "x=1 (1)" ignoring the chapter number.  How do I get that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the package `chngcntr`

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{equation}{chapter} % remove the chapter number
% \counterwithin{equation}{chapter}  % add the chapter number
\begin{document}
\chapter{hello}
\begin{equation}
x=1
\end{equation} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: After 2018, `chngcntr` is no longer needed as the functions are merged into the kernel.