# Numbering for Gather Equation: I want to remove the chapter number from equation numbering

Tags: equations, numbering, gather

I am novice to Lyx. I have used standard report for the document class. I created a gather equation. The equation numbering includes the number of the chapter which I do not want. I just want to number my equations 1,2,3 .........

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Does the answer to [How do I label equations without the chapter number?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/356109/134144)  help you?

Comment: I think @leandriis's link can solve

Comment: Yes, it is worked. Thanks a lot.